# How to get selected terms from Taxonomy web tagging control

Tags: 2013, managed-metadata, visual-web-part, taxonomy

I have created a web part in which there is one taxonomy picker control to enable user to select department.

I want to store the selected term to the list column which is of type `Managed Metadata`.

The declarative part is:

```
 <tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblProjectOwnerDepartment" runat="server" Text="Owner Department"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <Taxonomy:TaxonomyWebTaggingControl OnLoad="taxProjectOwnerDepartment_Load" ID="taxProjectOwnerDepartment" runat="server" Visible="true" IsDisplayPickerButton="true" IsMulti="false"
              AllowFillIn="false" IsAddTerms="false" IsIncludePathData="false"></Taxonomy:TaxonomyWebTaggingControl>

        </td>
    <td>

        <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvProjectOwnerDepartment" runat="server" OnServerValidate="cvProjectOwnerDepartment_ServerValidate"  />

    </td>
</tr>
```

How do I get the terms? I searched over internet but only found the articles to get terms from sharepoint.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

### TaxonomyWebTaggingControl on the server side

[TaxonomyWebTaggingControl.Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomywebtaggingcontrol.text%28v=office.14%29.aspx) Property is used to set or get value that represent a Term object

> Get values from this control as pairs of labels and GUIDs. The
>   delimiter between a label and a GUID is the | character. When using
>   multiple values, delimit them with a ; character. 
>   Example:
>   `term1|12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012;term2|87654321-4321-4321-4321-210987654321`

---

### TaxonomyWebTaggingControl on the client side

There is an alternative way to access and manipulate TaxonomyWebTaggingControl from client side Client side

For example to get Taxonomy control value

```
//Get Taxonomy ControlObject value
//webTaggingId - TaxonomyWebTaggingControl ID  
function getTaxonomyControlObjectValue(webTaggingId) {
    var webTaggingCtl = $get(webTaggingId);
    var taxCtlObj = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.ControlObject(webTaggingCtl);
    var termValue = taxCtlObj.getRawText();
    return termValue;
}
```

For more details refer this post - [Using SharePoint TaxonomyWebTaggingControl control: Access and manipulate from client side](http://blog.vgrem.com/2013/01/23/using-sharepoint-taxonomywebtaggingcontrol-control-access-and-manipulate-from-client-side/)

Answer (score -1):

**Control Definition**

```
<Taxonomy:TaxonomyWebTaggingControl id="**txtFileType**" runat="server" IsAddTerms="True" IsDisplayPickerButton="True" AllowFillIn="false">
```

**How to call from javascript**

```
var txtFileType = GetTerm("txtFileType");
```

**Javascript function**

```
function GetTerm(controlname) {

    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

        {
            if (inputs[i].id.indexOf(controlname) > 0) {
                var b = inputs[i].getElementsByTagName("input");


                    if(b[0].value == "")    
                        return "";

                    if(b[0].value.indexOf("|") == -1 || b[0].value.indexOf("-2222-2222-2222-") > 0)
                        {
                                alert("Invalid value " + b[0].value.split("|")[0] + ". Please select from list");
                                return "error";
                        }
                return b[0].value.split("|")[0];
            }
        }
    }
}
```